# Change image url on div hover instead image hover

Tags: jquery, html, hover

I am trying to change the url of image on mouseover, its working fine but what I am trying is, hover on div instead of image and change the image url

following the `jQuery` I have:

```
$(".logo > img").on({
   "mouseover" : function() {
   this.src = 'images/logo-white.png';
   },
   "mouseout" : function() {
   this.src='images/logo-black.png';
 }
```

HTML

```
<div class="logo">
   <img src="images/logo-white.png">
</div>
```

How do I make it on div hover? please help!

Comment: Do you have any unique class or id for image?

Comment: No unique class, image is just placed within a div

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is the HTML

```
<div class="logo">
   <img src="images/logo-white.png">
</div>
```

then this will work:

```
$(".logo").on({
  "mouseover": function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "images/logo-white.png");
  },
  "mouseout": function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "images/logo-black.png");
  }
});
```

Alternative: .hover - which is using less `}`

```
$(".logo").hover(
  function() {$(this).find("img").attr("src", "images/logo-white.png");},
  function() {$(this).find("img").attr("src", "images/logo-black.png");}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".logo").on({
   "mouseover" : function() {
     $(".logo img").attr("src","images/logo-white.png");
   },
   "mouseout" : function() {
   $(".logo img").attr("src","images/logo-white.png");
 }
```

Comment: incorrect jQuery. A jQuery object does not have a .src

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.logo').hover(function () {
             $(this).find('img').attr('src','images/logo-white.png');
           }, 
                    function () {
              $(this).find('img').attr('src','images/logo-black.png');
           }
        );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nkugogop/2/

Comment: That still only hovers the image.